# A single word meaning "Better results"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Does anybody know of a single word which describes a method or mechanism which is more reliable in getting the best answer (to a question which has no "correct" answers) or provides better results than the status quo?

Comment: An improvement?

Comment: Heuristics? ...

Comment: *The best **alternative*** - for a question without a definite answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the business, industrial and emergency services world, the concept of "best practices" is used to denote what is best under the circumstances rather than having a "one size fits all" rule or process.  It takes into account the means, ability, experience that is available in a real world situation and is constantly being evaluated and updated based on personal experience and new information.  Not a single word but it communicates the concept that you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply describe such a method as "preferred."

"Preferred" implies that the method or mechanism being described is more effective and accurate than an inferior method or mechanism.

Edit: If you are looking for a noun which denotes a "preferred method," I am unable to help.